# Check if file in the shared folder is not opened by another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file-io

I have a `file.pdf` in the shared folder in Windows 10. There are many users that
can open the file.
I tried to check if the file is opened with the following code:

```
import psutil
import os.path

documents_dir = r"X:\docs"
file_name = "file.pdf"
os.chdir(documents_dir)
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # this returns the list of opened files by the current process
            flist = proc.open_files()
            if flist:
                #print(proc.pid,proc.name)
                for f in flist:
                    if f.path == os.path.abspath(file_name):
                        print ("file {} is opened".format(file_name))
                        return

        # This catches a race condition where a process ends
        # before we can examine its files
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess as err:
            print("****",err)
```

I can't naturally catch the cases when users from another computer open the `file.pdf` in the shared Windows folder. Can I fix it?